# Refactor jQuery inview event listener

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to convert the following code to pure JavaScript.

```
$(function () {
    $('h2,.single').on('inview', function () {
        $(this).addClass('is-show');
    });
});
```

I tried much time but still can not figure out how. Any helps?

Comment: I this you want something like this in Javascript: https://codepen.io/jr-cologne/pen/zdYdmx

Comment: `I tried much time` - what did you try, and what happened?  Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and how to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Don'tPanic, Because our project migrate jquery to react and javascript. So, we want to use javascript instead of jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inview was an old plugin to solve a problem that now has a web API, as long as you don't need to support IE you can use [intersection observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) to do this.

Without any example or further explanation of how you need things to function it's hard to guess what you want to achieve. But here's a basic implementation that would mimic the tiny bit of JQuery you provided.

```js
const sections = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".single"));

function createObserver(el) {
  let observer;

  const options = {
    root: null,
    rootMargin: "0px",
    threshold: 0.5
  };

  observer = new IntersectionObserver(handleIntersect, options);
  observer.observe(el);
}

function handleIntersect(entries, observer) {
  entries.forEach((entry) => {
    let box = entry.target;
    let visible = entry.intersectionRatio;
    if(visible > 0.5) {
      box.classList.add('is-show');
    } else {
      box.classList.remove('is-show');
    }
  });
}



const setup = (sections) => {
  for (let i in sections) {
    const el = sections[i];
    createObserver(el);
  }
}


setup(sections);
```

```css
.single {
  padding: 2rem;
  background: tomato;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 600px 0;
  transition: all .5s ease-out;
  opacity: 0;
}
.is-show {
  opacity: 1
}
```

```html
<h2 class="single">I'm an H2 Element in frame</h2>
<h2 class="single">I'm an H2 Element in frame</h2>
<h2 class="single">I'm an H2 Element in frame</h2>
<h2 class="single">I'm an H2 Element in frame</h2>
```

Comment: That is exactly what i want. Thanks !!.

Answer (score 1):

Except the event you can use this:

```
(function() {
     document.querySelector("h2, .single").addEventListener("click", function(){
         this.classList.add("is-show");
  });
})();
```

I didn't find an equivalent for inview. You can refer to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events).